# Remove bottom border of DataTable

Tags: html, css, datatable

[DataTable example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFwZI.png)

I used [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) plugin to create a table like above picture (Please note that the picture is just an example, my table doesnt have footer). Now I want to remove the bottom border. Problem is my css doesnt override the default border style.
I use line below to create a DataTable

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

My html

```
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

However, when I try to remove the bottom border using my own css, it doesnt work

```
    table.dataTable.no-footer {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
```

Is there another way to remove the bottom border?

Comment: It works fine on my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjake/qxknjb9s/), something else must be causing your issue. Either you set a border somewhere else in your CSS or something else is affecting your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always use !important for your css to gain the most level of importance. 
its needed and good to use specially when you are trying to override a plugin's css.
like:

```
table.dataTable.no-footer {
        border-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
```

of course if your css selector (table.dataTable.no-footer) is the right one!

this is the reference for how css processors specify selectors level of importance:

[How is specificity calculated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thanks @Mamdasan, I added !important to my CSS just 1 seconds before your answer, lol. And this is the answer that solved my problem

Comment: That's not a good solution. Avoid using !important at all cost.

Comment: @Jake, yes, but in my case, I found that there are many border CSS apply on the same table. And I want to prioritize my own style, so I added !important. This answer may not be the best, but it solved my problem :D

Answer (score 1):

You write the wrong CSS selector. Try to use this one, and add class .no-footer to your table:

```
.dataTable.no-footer tfoot th, 
.dataTable.no-footer tfoot td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: DataTable has this default CSS : `table.dataTable.no-footer { border-bottom: 1px solid #111; }` so in this case I think he is using the right selector.

Comment: Ok, In this case, I guess you have wrong ordering of css files. You should include css file in right position. Firstly you include css for DataTable, after that your custom css